# Explanation for 3D rotation about the axis. (Simple coding)

Tags: c++, 3d, matrix, rotation

I was preparing for my test but I need help understanding rotation about the axis.  In one question I am to assume a function `drawHouse()` which draws a wire frame house in the xy-plane as shown in this image:

[image: house before transformation]

We are given multiple choices of segments of code and asked which one would result in this transformed house:

[image]

The right answer is as follows: but I am not sure if the commands are executed from back to front or front to back:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
glScalef(2, 1, 1); 
glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1); 
glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0); 
drawHouse();
```

The problem is that I do not know WHICH way to rotate on WHICH axis so if anyone can give me a brief summary on that, I will be obliged.

[Original question is 22 on here, PDF](http://cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci373s1c/exams/CS373Test2011_SampleSolution.pdf)

Comment: Some people may find it really easy but I just get confused a little so please keep that in consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have documentation for the `gl` functions and the order in which the transformations get applied. If you look at the transformations in terms of the axes being fixed, then the solution only makes sense if the transformations happen in reverse order, i.e. starting with `glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);`. So the transformations would be

1. rotate by 180 degrees about the X axis, leavung the house pointing downwards
2. rotate by 90 degrees about the Z axis, leaving the house lying on the X axis as in the final image, without stretching
3. scale *2 along the X axis, stretching the house out

Comment: Hi there, I am aware of the order of transformations and yes I do have the notes. Yes your answer makes sense

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** this text is completely different to the (incorrect) answer that was accepted, but I couldn't delete my answer after it was accepted.

The transformations are applied in reverse order.

The first rotation (last in the function) flips the house upside down by rotating around the `x` axis.

The second rotates it around the `z` axis so that it points right.

The final scaling function stretches it along the `x` axis.

Comment: Thank you! it somewhat makes sense now

Comment: @jay that isn't consistent with the scaling. If the ordering were like that, the house would be stretched out in wall to wall direction, not floor to roof.

Comment: @juanchopanza you're right - I didn't notice the asymmetric scaling.

Comment: Hi, I think I know why, according to my lecturer we are meant to start with the rotation first. Pretty much the code is executed backwards starting from rotation. If you do that then the just before the translation the part of the object on X axis is scaled properly

Comment: @jay that's more or less what I said in my answer :-)

Comment: @jay please accept the other answer - mine was originally completely wrong.

Comment: @Alnitak Hi, should it not be "The second rotates it around the z axis so that it points right."??